# Probability that two points are more distant than a third equidistant point

Tags: probability, geometry

Say you have three points $x,y,z \in \mathbf{R}^n$ with standard Euclidean distance $d$ and $d(x,y) = d(y,z)$. Then what's the probability that $d(x,z) > d(x,y)$ for random $x,z$? For convenience, $y=\mathbf{0}$ and $d(x,y) = d(y,z) = 1$.

For $n=3$, I'm guessing it's

$$
p(d(x,z) > 1) = p(d(x,z)>1|x=(1,0,0)) 
\\
=1-A(z,1) / 4\pi
\\
\approx 3/4
$$

where $A(z,r)$ is the area for the set of points $\{z|d(z,(1,0,0))<r,d(z,\mathbf{0})=1\}$. I don't know how that would be calculated but I assume $\pi$ is a bad approximation for it.

For $n$ in general? Is there a closed form for this probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$, we find $p_1=\frac12$.
For $n=2$, we find $p_2=\frac23$.
For general $n$, we find
$$p_n=1-\frac{\int_0^{\frac\pi3}(\sin \phi)^{n-2} \,\mathrm d\phi}{\int_0^{\pi}(\sin \phi)^{n-2} \,\mathrm d\phi}.$$
Especially, the value for $n=3$ is *exactly*
$$p_3=1-\frac{\int_0^{\frac\pi3}\sin \phi \,\mathrm d\phi}{\int_0^{\pi}\sin \phi \,\mathrm d\phi}=1-\frac{\cos 0-\cos \frac\pi3 }{\cos 0-\cos \pi}=\frac34.$$

*Warning:* $p_4=\frac23+\frac{\sqrt 3}{4\pi}\ne \frac45$.